# React Native Global state

Tags: ios, state, react-native

I have a state variable that is set on one of my pages but I want that state value to also be accessible on another page. Not quite sure how this is achieved.

For example on mainpage.ios.js

```
var MainPage = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      value: 1
    };
  },
```

Then on otherpage.ios.js I want to update based on what that value was already set to on the previous page. The different pages are selected through Tab bar. So basically that value would be effectively global between all pages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never mind, I found out how to do it. For anyone who doesn't know, here is how I did it. As far as I can see, there is no global states, you just need to pass props to each page component.

So for mainpage.ios.js you require otherpage.ios.js:

```
 var OtherPage = require('./otherpage');
```

and then when you use the element you include pass props:

```
    <OtherPage value={2}/>
```

Or

```
    <OtherPage value={this.state.value}/>
```

Then on otherpage.ios.js you could then reference that variable as you wish using: this.props.value.

Comment: Its not really perfect though because its merely Parent Child communication. Still not sure how to do Child Parent communication. The variable is far from global as it is but unfortunately the documentation for React Native is sparse to say the least, there's nothing on there about this.

Comment: one thing you should always rely on is single flow. if you want your child to talk to your parent. Simply trigger an action which goes into store and change something. now store will notify the parent the new update. if you do this, the logics are become a lot easier.

Answer (score 4):

To get a shared global state between multiple components with React Native, you should take advantage of a Flux implementation. I personally prefer redux but you can use any which one you like. Here's an example of redux with React Native: https://github.com/alinz/example-react-native-redux